# Nebula.gl DrawPolygonMode not snapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

I am quite new to nebula.gl, and I have been trying to use the DrawPolygonMode snapping to features I am dropping on the editable layer (not other layers).

The setting [modeConfig](https://nebula.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/editable-geojson-layer) says that `additionalSnapTargets` is not required, and the snap should occur anyway. This is not currently happening with this code:

```
// index.tsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DeckGL from 'deck.gl';
import { EditableGeoJsonLayer, DrawPolygonMode } from 'nebula.gl';
import { StaticMap } from 'react-map-gl';

// ...
// const viewState = ...
// const MAPBOX_TOKEN = ...

const selectedFeatureIndexes = [] as any;

const editableLayer = new EditableGeoJsonLayer({
    id: 'geojson',
    data: geojson,
    pickable:true,
    //@ts-ignore
    modeConfig:{
      enableSnapping:true
    },
    //@ts-ignore
    mode: DrawPolygonMode,
    pickingRadius:100,
    selectedFeatureIndexes,
    //@ts-ignore
      onEdit: (e) => {setGeojson(e.updatedData)}
  });

export function Map(props:any){
  const [geojson, setGeojson] = useState({
    type: 'FeatureCollection' as any,
    features: [] as any} as any)

return(
      <DeckGL
      width='100%'
      height='100%'
      layers={[editableLayer]}
      viewState={viewState}
      controller={true}>
        <StaticMap
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} />
      </DeckGL>
    );
}
```

is there any callback I am missing or is the function not available when drawing polygons? The [advanced example](https://github.com/uber/nebula.gl/blob/master/examples/advanced/src/example.tsx) shows how to do this with translation, but I am not sure to get if that's applicable to the `DrawPolygonMode` mode. Also, `mode : new SnappableMode(new DrawPolygonMode())` does not produce the effect I am about.

Also, I have to put several `//@ts-ignore` as `EditableGeoJsonLayer` does not recognise some arguments (among which, `mode`).

Thank you in advance